# Is it possible to send an email via Google App Engine from an alias?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

Is it possible to send an email using Google App Engine (GAE) from a Google Apps user account alias?

Since we are using a "custom" domain with our app (e.g., "www.example.com"), Google requires us to use a Google Apps paid account to enable web site HTTPS, which is a hidden cost when considering the cost of hosting.

We don't want to have pay for extra accounts for things like "support@example.com", so we've just set that up as an alias of the paid account.  And I don't want to have to be checking multiple accounts. But now we can't figure out how to send email from "support@example.com".

This article explains [email sending options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#Python_Sending_mail), but when I try to use the domain account approach, it basically ends up canonicalizing the support email alias and tells me that my account is already authorized.  Anyway, I can't seem to figure out how to get any of the approaches to work for my situation.  Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: I was never able to do this with app engine.  To get around it, I use Amazon SES to send email for my app engine app.  Amazon SES lets you do this and has more features as well.

Comment: I had the very same problem a while back and couldn't find a solution using the App Engine Mail API, so it looks like the answer is _No_

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find a solution for this as well, but Unfortunately there does not seem to be any way to send email from domain alias registered to Google Apps using GAE. Or any other domain for that matter.

There is an open ticket with low priority opened here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2766
So I don't have high hopes as the ticket has been open for 5 years.